# Next 5 working dates

Tags: google-sheets

I’m trying to find a way in Google Sheets to list the dates for the next 5 working days. I’ve got it to show me the next working week, however as today is a Wednesday ideally I would like the date for tomorrow and Friday, and then Monday Tuesday Wednesday.

I’m thinking it’s probably simple and I need to change my set up as at the moment I have mon-Friday listed and I wanted the dates out of the way and just the relevant data to filter through via lookup ... but I’m not sure if it’s even possible.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Show the formulas that you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(WORKDAY(TODAY(),SEQUENCE(5,1,1,1)))
```

[WORKDAY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093059?hl=en-GB) returns date after number of working days (in this case 5 and to make it a list [SEQUENCE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en-GB) is used) starting from [TODAY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984?hl=en).